# My php pdo class takes too much time to execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I made a php database class with pdo for using my project. Its very simple. But I noticed one thing that, It takes too much time to execute. Can you tell me where I did wrong?

Here is my Database Class code

```
class database{


    public $error;

    private $db;
    private $dbhost = 'localhost';
    private $dbname = 'support_database';
    private $dbuser = 'root';
    private $dbpass = '';
    public $site_url = "http://localhost/support";

    public function connect(){

        try {
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->dbhost};dbname={$this->dbname}",$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
           // echo "Connection error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function deleteRecord($id){
        $this->Connect();
        $statement = $this->db->prepare("delete from officers_table where id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($id));
    }

    public function showRecord($tablename){
        $this->Connect();
        $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from $tablename");
        $statement->execute();
        return $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    }

    public function addRecord($tablename,$fields,$values){
        $this->Connect();

        $items = $fields;
        $id = count($items);
        $newarray = array();
        for($i = 0; $i<$id; $i++){
            $newarray[] = "?";
        }

        $nval = implode(",",$newarray);

        $fields = implode(",",$fields);

        $statement = $this->db->prepare("insert into $tablename ($fields) values($nval)");
        $statement->execute($values);

        return true;
    }

    public function addUser($tablename,$fields,$values){
        $this->Connect();

        $items = $fields;
        $id = count($items);
        $newarray = array();
        for($i = 0; $i<$id; $i++){
            $newarray[] = "?";
        }

        $nval = implode(",",$newarray);

        $fields = implode(",",$fields);

        $statement = $this->db->prepare("insert into $tablename ($fields) values($nval)");
        $statement->execute($values);

        return true;
    }

    public function checkUser($tablename,$field,$value){
        $this->Connect();

        $num = 0;
        $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from $tablename where $field=?");
        $statement->execute(array($value));     

        $num = $statement->rowCount();

        if($num>0) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function SingleValueSearch($tablename,$field,$value,$id="id",$ordertype="DESC"){
        $this->Connect();

        $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from $tablename where $field=? order by $id $ordertype");
        $statement->execute(array($value));     

        return $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function allTicket($tablename){
        $this->Connect();

        $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from $tablename order by id DESC");
        $statement->execute();      

        return $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function userTicket($tablename,$field,$value,$id="id",$ordertype="DESC"){
        $this->Connect();


        $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from $tablename where $field=? order by $id $ordertype");
        $statement->execute(array($value));     

        return $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function currentUserId($email){
        $this->Connect();

        $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from support_users where email=?");
        $statement->execute(array($email));     

        return $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function lastId($tablename){
        $this->Connect();
        $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from $tablename order by id DESC LIMIT 1");
        $statement->execute();
        return $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    }


    public function emptyCheck($tablename,$user_id,$user_role){
        $this->Connect();

        $num = 0;

        if($user_role == 'admin'){
            $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from $tablename");
            $statement->execute();      

            $num = $statement->rowCount();

            if($num>0){
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        else{

            $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from $tablename where user_id =?");
            $statement->execute(array($user_id));       

            $num = $statement->rowCount();

            if($num>0){
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


    }

    public function fileCheck($name) {
      foreach ($_FILES[$name]['error'] as $ferror) {
        if ($ferror != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    public function deleteTicket($id){
        $this->Connect();

        $statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from support_tickets where id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($id));
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $media_id = unserialize($result[0]['media_id']);

        foreach( $media_id as $mid ){

            $statement = $this->db->prepare("delete from support_media where id=?");
            $statement->execute(array($mid));

        }

        $statement = $this->db->prepare("delete from support_tickets where id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($id));

        return true;
    }

}
```

And in my project I am using something like this. The below link's code taking long time to execute.I have used more my queries only on this page.

https://pastebin.com/0UhETNgG

Please help me to find out the mistake I made. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add _all_ relevant code into your _question_, not as an off site link. If that link changes or gets removed, this question will be useless for future visitors.

Comment: Not only are you fetching the same record over and over: `$db->SingleValueSearch('support_tickets','id',$_GET['id'],'id','DESC')` from the database, you're also creating _a new db-connection_ every time. In your `connect()`, return the current connection if it exists by adding `if ($this->db) return $this->db` in the start. Then, fetch the record _once_ and  store it in a variable. Keep using that variable instead of querying the db over and over.

Comment: I am sorry sir for hosting the code off site. Because the codes did not look right here. :(

Comment: Thank you so much. I've changed my code. Its working like a Rocket.

Comment: I can add it as an answer so you can accept it and close the question.

Comment: Ok Sir. Add an answer. I will accept it and close the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some optimizations you can do in your existing code.

#### The database connection

You're currently creating a new connection on every query to the db. This is expensive so you should reuse the current connection instead.

Add this in the beginning of your `connect()` method:

```
public function connect(){
    if ($this->db) {
        // There already is a connection, return it instead
        return $this->db;
    }

    // Your current try/catch block
}
```

#### Repeating the same query over and over

You're also fetching the same record from the database over and over within the same script. Even though DB calls are fast (assuming that the db is indexed correctly), it's still an unnecessary overhead. You should fetch it *once*, store it in a variable and reuse the variable:

```
$ticket = $db->SingleValueSearch('support_tickets','id',$_GET['id'],'i‌​d','DESC');
```

Now you can replace all identical calls to use the variable `$ticket` instead.

Answer (score -1):

According to  [Magnus Eriksson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson) instructions I did Change my code. Now Its working like a Rocket :) Thank you so much Sir.

Here is my Connect method's code. I just changed here with a if condition.

```
public function connect(){

        try {
            if($this->db){
                return $this->db;
            }
            else{
                $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->dbhost};dbname={$this->dbname}",$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass);
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }

        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
           // echo "Connection error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added a real answer that you can accept. Also, the `if`-statement should be outside of your `try/catch`